# Routes - Tidily define multiple resources with customisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, refactoring

My routes are getting out of hand due to the fact that this isn't possible (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
map.resources :english_pages, :as => :english, :spanish_pages, :as => :spanish do |article|
```

Due to nested routes things are spiralling out of control (tidiness).

```
map.resources :english_pages, :as => :english, :member => {:manage => :get} do |article|
  article.resources :topics do |topic|
    topic.resources :posts
  end
end
map.resources :spanish_pages, :as => :spanish do |article|
  article.resources :topics do |topic|
    topic.resources :posts
  end
end
```

How can I avoid duplication of this:

```
article.resources :topics do |topic|
  topic.resources :posts
end
```

Is there some way to store routes as a block somewhere, or perhaps define, in my case, english_pages and spanish pages aliases seperately?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a little bit of meta-programming.

resources is just a method call, and the symbols end up being evaluated as strings anyway, so this becomes pretty easy.

```
[:english, :spanish].each do |language|
  map.resource "#{language}_pages", :as => language, :member => {:manage => :get} do |article| 
    article.resources :topics do |topic|
    topic.resources :posts
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, should have known it would be something simple.